# Where are the cvCreateCameraCapture, cvCreateFileCapture, etc in JavaCV?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I've been trying to follow tutorials for javacv from various tutorial sites, but the biggest problem was that almost every single tutorials use cvCreate... methods to bring images and videos. But when I type those in, I can't find the methods in any libraries. I downloaded the latest javacv-bin file from bytedeco and added all the libraries from that download to my project, but it's still not working. Other classes such as Mat, CvCapture work perfectly. What can be the problem?

here's one tutorial i've been following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oliqc3B9Wrc&index=3&list=PLDk0xqo2QeH-4XZ93KH38jOoGOd60-2GO

P.S.
Can you recommand any javacv and java tutorial for beginners?
I'm stuck trying to use built in webcam on my laptop to do basic camera features such as capturing and recording.

Comment: oh, and I'm using Windows 8.1 and Eclipse Mars

Comment: why don't you use [OpenCV for Java](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)?

Comment: I wanted to, but then when I try to search for tutorials, a lot of them uses javacv instead of opencv. I would use opencv definitely if there's a way to EASILY find all the classes and methods I can use and their usage explanations as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you statically import packages like below ?

```
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_videoio.*;
```

Comment: thx for the reply. I tried static import but got some errors later on. So I just gave up on that tutorial and started studying with books from amazon. Things are working a little better, but still with hundreds of errors again. I'll just vote you up as answer and close this question.

Comment: This does solve the problem, mentioned in the question however. I just want to know, how do you know this? Where can I find a comprehensive guide on where each class is, and what it does?